# Am I able to search for specific transactions based what's in the program instruction logs?

Tags: program, instructions, logs

I'm interested in trying to find all transactions for a specific program that include a specific instruction. Take this  Mango transaction for example, I can see that someone is placing multiple Perp Orders: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4xMtowmeRpcoyvXMqsmckKvTrkkNoCibinvrQ2ZJtnBtPAvj7xXTVn7jb3oRsf2KFCWjmFMMHSZua4AtAUkP26MW.

Here and in many other programs useful information is outputted in the program instruction logs. Ideally I'd like to search for specific transactions based on messages in the logs. Is there a good way to do this? I know some people use Geyser plugins and PostgreSQL for this purpose, but I don't have access to a validator so I'm not sure what my options are.

Answer (score 2):

All Geyser plugin does is it streams current account updates and transactions. Unless you need listen to many programs, you can do the same with RPC by using subscribe to websocket API.

To subscribe to program logs, you can use [logsSubscribe](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#logssubscribe) method. When you find the information you need in log, you can use [getTransaction](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) method to get all details of this transaction including its instructions.

Comment: It seem that logSubscribe would only give me events as they happen correct? If I'm  interested in looking back in time a week or month, I think I'd need something like getSignaturesForAddress combined with a bunch of getTransaction calls